# Local Kibana not Connecting to Local Elasticsearch Server (StreamCorruptedException?)

Tags: configuration, elasticsearch, local, kibana

So I set up Elasticsearch, I have the server running. When I connect to `http://localhost:9200/` I get the status message. It is version number `1.4.3`.

Now I download Kibana 3.1.2. As instruced in the readme, I add the following lines to `elasticsearch.yml`, the config file:

```
# making kibana local work
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: 127.0.0.1
```

I also add the following lines to Kibana's `config.js`:

```
elasticsearch: 'http://localhost:9200',
```

When I navigate to Kibana's `index.html` in my up-to-date Firefox, I get a page stating that:

```
Connection Failed
Possibility #1: Your elasticsearch server is down or unreachable.......
```

Now I've tried some other variables for the config files, but it seems like it should work. Both are present on my local Ubuntu 14.04/64bit install.

When I check `elasticsearch.log`, I find the following:

```
[2015-02-18 13:50:12,697][INFO ][node                     ] [Puma] version[1.4.3], pid[14592], build[36a29a7/2015-02-11T14:23:15Z]
[2015-02-18 13:50:12,698][INFO ][node                     ] [Puma] initializing ...
[2015-02-18 13:50:12,706][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Puma] loaded [], sites []
[2015-02-18 13:50:16,540][INFO ][node                     ] [Puma] initialized
[2015-02-18 13:50:16,540][INFO ][node                     ] [Puma] starting ...
[2015-02-18 13:50:16,735][INFO ][transport                ] [Puma] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.192.25:9300]}
[2015-02-18 13:50:16,761][INFO ][discovery                ] [Puma] elasticsearch/zEjlD0HdR2OtpjykOo1e7g
[2015-02-18 13:50:20,542][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Puma] new_master [Puma][zEjlD0HdR2OtpjykOo1e7g][zirconcode][inet[/192.168.192.25:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-02-18 13:50:20,569][INFO ][http                     ] [Puma] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.192.25:9200]}
[2015-02-18 13:50:20,570][INFO ][node                     ] [Puma] started
[2015-02-18 13:50:20,632][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Puma] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2015-02-18 13:50:29,195][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Puma] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x8e5c4505, /127.0.0.1:53332 => /127.0.0.1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (47,45,54,20)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-02-18 13:50:29,202][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Puma] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x8e5c4505, /127.0.0.1:53332 :> /127.0.0.1:9300]], closing connection
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (47,45,54,20)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:47)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:425)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:482)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:574)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.NettyTransport.exceptionCaught(NettyTransport.java:622)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(MessageChannelHandler.java:234)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've only been getting this error once in multiple attempts though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
http.cors.allow-origin: 127.0.0.1
```

in your ES 1.4.3 elasticsearch.yml try

```
http.cors.allow-origin: "http://127.0.0.1"
```

That assumes you're running kibana on port 80

The above will work if you access kibana from `http://127.0.0.1/kibana`. If you use the url `http://localhost/kibana` instead, replace `127.0.0.1` with `localhost` in your yml file

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately I still get the same error. I open Kibana in the browser so I assume it is port 80, is there any way to check?

Comment: If you can access kibana from `http://127.0.0.1/kibana` then I'm not sure why that's not working. If you use `http://localhost/kibana` instead, try using localhost in your yml file

Comment: I can access Kibana via `http://127.0.0.1/kibana-3.1.2/` yes. I thought firefox's caching was messing with me for a second but I turned it off and still no dice.

Comment: I've switched to Kibana 4 rc1 and have gotten things to work without a hitch. Still not sure what the problem was but it's no longer relevant I suppose.

Comment: If you add a suggestion in your answer to switch I will accept it, I think that is all right =)

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps to solve above problem:

1. Open file `elasticsearch<Version>/config/elasticsearch.yml`
2. Add one line `http.cors.allow-origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5601"`

Now start elasticserch and then start Kibana. It will now connect.